# Directive with isolate scope property on ngSelect element to pre-select option: It randomly loses value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

It looks like this. I load my page and my form displays with values fetched. These values are being fetched by an http service. At the top of the form there is my custom directive (select box):

```
        .directive('categorySelectBox', function(){

            return {
                restrict: "A",
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    // all properties here need to be added to 
                    // the directive in order to be picked up
                    taxonomies: '='
                    ,chosen: '='
                },
                templateUrl: "ngapp/js/tpl/select-box.html"
            };

    })
```

the directive template:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-options="option.label for option in taxonomies track by option.value" 
    ng-model="chosen" 
    chosen="chosen" 
    taxonomies="taxonomies">
<option value="">Please select a category</option>
```

My controller is like this:

```
        .controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'DbResourceSrv', function($scope, DbResourceSrv){

            $scope.$watch('cid', function() {
                $scope.formBusy = true;
                $scope.c = DbResourceSrv.getDbResource('response.php', 'company', $scope.cid)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            $scope.c = data;
                            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                                $scope.c.push({key: value});
                            });
                        });

                $scope.tax = DbResourceSrv.getDbResource('response.php', 'taxonomy', '')
                        .then(function(data) {
                            $scope.taxonomies = [];
                            $scope.chosen = [];
                            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                                $scope.taxonomies.push({label: value.name, value: value.term_taxonomy_id});
                            });
                            // subtract 1 because $scope.c is 0-based
                            var catId = $scope.c.category - 1;
                            $scope.chosen = $scope.taxonomies[catId];
                            $scope.formBusy = false;
                        });
            });


            $scope.updateCompany = function(cid) {
                var formData = $scope.c;
                $scope.formBusy = true;
                $scope.doCompanyUpdate = DbResourceSrv.updateDbResource('response.php', cid, formData)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $scope.formBusy = false;
                        });
            };
    }]);
```

Usually I do see my category (which is also fetched from the database, just in a separate call `$scope.tax`

Now, I tried with `$watch`ing the chosen scope property but it doesnt change anything. I also tried using a directive controller to make sure `scope.chosen` is set there but it seems to me even though I'm loading both processes with promises - the category fetching misfires when one is loaded before the other because they are tied too tightly.

Any suggestions for code improvement so i can avoid seeing the default `Please select a category` option selected on page load?

Comment: I know it's a bit of a pain, but if you're still stumped and wouldn't mind making a Plunker/Fiddle/JSBin demonstrating the problem, I'd be glad to try to help. There's too much for me to wrap my head around here without seeing the problem and being able to fiddle around with code.

Comment: @MarcKline How can I mimic my `$http` services for this purpose (plunker)?

Comment: If they are GET methods, just add a file containing sample data, and then you can use a relative URL. e.g. populate a file called `example.json` with sample data, then `$http.get('example.json')`.

Comment: @MarcKline If you could take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/ZDk75o (note you will have to do a small trick to make it load json - i really suck at creating these things). I'm going to proceed with creation of another json file containing categories

Comment: Actually, I think I found the issue. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct: you have two promises which aren't guaranteed to resolve in order, and this is a problem. In the case where the second "beats" the first, it won't be able to calculate `catId`, since `$scope.c` isn't populated yet.

```
$scope.c = DbResourceSrv.getDbResource('response.php', 'company', $scope.cid)
.then(function(data) {
    $scope.c = data; // not guaranteed to be set when it's needed
});

$scope.tax = DbResourceSrv.getDbResource('response.php', 'taxonomy', '')
.then(function(data) {
    var catId = $scope.c.category - 1;
    $scope.chosen = $scope.taxonomies[catId];
});
```

A solution is to use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#all), which accepts an array of promises as an argument and returns another promise which is resolved only when *all* of the passed in promises resolve.

It would look something like this:

```
$q.all([$scope.c, $scope.tax]).then(function(results){
    var catId = $scope.c.category - 1;
    $scope.chosen = $scope.taxonomies[catId];
});
```

[Proof of concept demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LL2dWuoebq6U5bwTuOku?p=preview)

You should be able to leave the bulk of your existing promise callbacks in tact - just move whatever relies on both AJAX requests having returned.

Comment: I assume I have to set dependency on `$q` ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to inject it into the controller.

Comment: Ok, I will play with the code now and see if i can make it work. At the moment I'm not getting any category preselected at all but I assume code needs some tweaking. i will also try to include `reason` etc. to see why it fails.
Anyway, i will accept your answer if `$q` proves to be working! Thank you

Comment: Sure. Here is [**a demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LL2dWuoebq6U5bwTuOku?p=preview) for proof of concept.

Comment: I'm not sure why but inside my `$q.all` my `$scope.c` is undefined, no matter if I keep it within the `$watch` block or I move it outside. Are you sure my http calls should keep their promises in this case (`.then()`)?

Comment: Might be easier to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54829/directive-with-isolate-scope-property-on-ngselect-element-to-pre-select-option-i)

Comment: For anyone who sees this in the future: this answer correctly pointed me in the right direction. But there was a catch - my foreach loop in `$scope.c` was redundant - i removed it and it started to work as expected